# How do I bisect along an axis?

Tags: objects

[image]Maybe I can't find the answer because I am not familiar yet with all the terminology. I know this is probably a simple answer but I cannot find it. How do I align the plane of a bisect along an axis?

I have an object that I want to bisect where 2 parts meet. The object is aligned to the platform and I want to make a cut through it the Z/Y axes.

Also... there is no tag for the bisect tool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Bisect](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bisect.html) tool has the *Plane Normal* option in its settings. It consists of 3 sliders for each axis with values between -1 and 1 which allow to control the orientation of the cutting plane.

The values below or above 0 will make the custom plane to be oriented towards that axis, while values of 0 or around mean that the plane will be oriented along that axis.

In your case enter `0` value for the Z axis:

[image: image-of-cut-monkey]

Answer (score 4):

You can use knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd>) instead.

While using knife tool:

<kbd>C</kbd> to lock to axes

<kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through

Make sure that you are in orthographic view (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)

[image]

[image]

<kbd>B</kbd> for border select

You could also use bisect and fiddle with it's options in your tool menu:

[image]

Comment: I like that... however, the bisect tool also has the option to fill the face as well...

Comment: try the other gif cough didnt see that you added that picture cough