# How can I stretch portion of a model along a plane/axis?

Tags: modeling, objects, transforms

Please see image here for what I'd like to do:

[image]

I want to add stretch a portion of the part by 1mm-2mm right at the location of the plane in the image, along the Y (green) axis. This will increase the distance between the screw hole and the cylindrical portion of the part.

What is the easiest way to go about this? I've used a lot of CAD software in my time but learning Blender seems a bit more challenging. I've messed with a few things but the operation I want doesn't seem to be called what I think it'd be, or I'm just doing it wrong.

Help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: [Bisect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88578/how-do-i-bisect-along-an-axis) > Move > [Bridge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79697/connect-two-walls-with-a-curve)

Answer (score -1):

First you have to configure Blender to work with measurements, enable snap, select *increment* option (if I am not mistaken enable snap is not needed but do it just in case) then select the part that you want and press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> (if you want to move it to the right, don't add a `-` symbol, `+` means right, but you don't need to place `+` because it's implicit - blender assumes that) then the value that you want to add (`1` or `2` for example). For a more thorough explanation, see this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOxN4CHeBPQ

Comment: The markdown for keyboard keys is `<kbd>G</kbd>`

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your answers. Give them a little more structure by using paragraphs, learn about the [<kbd> tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs). Try to make use of the Shift key on your keyboard, when necessary ("I" instead of "i").

Comment: " I " in where?

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid first of all thanks for taking your time to help the community. I made another edit of your question to further improve it; keep in mind some edits could be unintentionally wrong, but edits are done in good faith to improve a question or an answer. Studying edits is a great way to improve your style, and if you want to discuss those changes, or ask what else you could improve (I think this answer is still in dire need of improvements), feel free to ask me or others on the *"Render Farm"* chat.

Comment: I just now see I got an excavator badge, I don't know why SE has put this thread on top yesterday :D

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ...........................